# Android: Design view of XML file is white and blank

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I created a menu folder under res folder and, in that menu folder, I created a file called drawer_menu.xml. This is the text of that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
            android:title="Message" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_my_events"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_my_events"
            android:title="Chat" />

    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

But the design view is white and blank. No element shows up.Also I don't get to see AppThemes option which usually shows up in layout xml files.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Android Studio Canary 3.2 and looks like that.

[image]

So maybe is a bug of your Android Studio version.

Comment: I see ! So should I proceed with this and complete designing my navigation drawer (this was the part of code for designing a navigation drawer) and, later check the output with my android phone?

Comment: I think so. Maybe is just a visual issue. Let me know if everything is alright when you test it at phone

Comment: You were right. It was just an issue with visualization. My navigation drawer is working perfectly. Thank you. :)

Comment: I am glad to know that. Happy coding @Debbie

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a problem with the Android Studio Preview which didn't load properly and needs to be checked. If you're using the latest Android Studio, try reopening-refreshing preview by clicking on Preview (in the right side of the app).

If this didn't solve the issue, double clicking on the Preview in the right side of the app when using code editor should show the preview or errors but i think it will be fixed by doing that since I've had the same issue and after reopening it, there were a `force refresh` for the layout and it fixed the issue somehow.

Comment: @Mohsen, I am not facing this issue for layout xml files.

Comment: Try removing these two lines: `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view"` and stop gradle in running then reopen the preview and it'll be fixed i hope.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing support libraries version to more stable as `27.1.1`

if you have 28 SDK version change to `28.0.0-alpha1`

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1
```

Comment: At present my dependency is : implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02' . Should I change it to yours? I am not facing this issue for layout xml files.

Comment: rc02 is the issue. Use below versions like `27.1.1`.