# Android Studio, DrawerLayout makes design view go blank

Tags: android

I am new to Android development so excuse me if I ask some dumb questions but I really can't figure out why whenever I switch from a relative layout or linear to a DrawerLayout my design view goes blank and only said "android....DrawerLayout".i loose all of the buttons textfields all of it goes away! I added all of the dependencies necessary to use it. All I need this drawer layout is to add a navigation view to my main screen. I have tried the  but it still nothing shows in the design view so I can't really lay things out properly without seeing how it is going to look! Any help will be really appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fcIi.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#CC809fff"

            android:padding="10dp">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/weatherView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:contextClickable="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/weather" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                android:padding="11dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="Weather"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#CC809fff"

            android:padding="10dp">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/news" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="#ff3300
"
                android:visibility="visible">

            </View>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="News"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#CC000000"
            android:padding="5dp">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/events_icon" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </View>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventsTextfield"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Events"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#CC000000"
            android:padding="5dp">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/trending_icon" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </View>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/secondview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hottest"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>



    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>





     MY DEPENDENCIES ARE THE FOLLOWING:
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    }



  --------- BUILD.GRADLE:PROJECT---------


     // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: There is the code. i added the dependencies at the bottom. Thank you

Comment: please share your project build.gradle

Comment: Can you try to change the theme from top bar above the preview 
currently AppTheme is there try to change

Comment: Remove navgationView also and check

Comment: The error is "Failed to find style 'cardViewStyle' in current theme"

Answer (score 0):

Most times this is usually because of Android studio cache issues. You can try to invalidate and restart your Android Studio by going to:

```
 File->Invalide Caches / Restart.
```

Once you have added all dependencies, this should solve your problem.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CardView you must include its dependency 
Add this dependency

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Did it. but nothing seems to change my design view but when i run the app on my phone it displays everything i'm just trying to get the design view to work. check out the picture i just uploaded

Comment: change theme on the bar where you see APPTHEME change it to other theme and try

Comment: i just try that but what it does it changes the color of screen not it doesnt seem to change the content such as the buttons or the images i have inserted. It so weird i have never run into this problem until i started using drawerLayout.

Comment: for Viewing other Items change visibilty of NavigationView to visibility = Gone

Comment: I am thinking it might be a bug in my version of android studio because i found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220326/android-design-view-of-xml-file-is-white-and-blank that had a similar issue. My version of android studio is "Android studio 3.1.4" built on july 23 18

Comment: Problem has been solved! i ran the new Android Studio Update and it is now working! Android studio 3.1.4 has redering problems with drawerLayout! Thanks everybody!